# Case Age between two dates excluding holiday and weekends

Tags: dax, measure

I want to calculate the case age as the difference
a. between two dates (created on Date and Completed On date), if the status = Close or Resolved or Cancelled Or
b. between two dates (created On and Today), if the status = Active

in Power BI, with the exclusion of holidays and Weekends.

Please note that I have a table which i have created a calendar table where I have specified the workdays and holidays and weekends.

Specifically, can someone please help me with the formula to calculate the Case Age in Power BI?

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

I am expecting a formula that will

1. calculate the date difference between the created date and today, with the exclusion of holidays and weekends if the status = Active
2. Calculate the date difference between created date and completed date, with the exclusion of holidays and weekends if the status = Completed or cancelled

I used this formula but how do i exclude holidays and weekends from it

Age = IF(Intakes[value.statecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue]="Active",
DATEDIFF(Intakes[value.createdon@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue],TODAY(),DAY),
DATEDIFF(Intakes[value.createdon@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue],Intakes[value.coc_completedon@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue],DAY))

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using this formular

```
Age = IF(Intakes[value.statecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue]="Active",
NETWORKDAYS(Intakes[value.createdon@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue],TODAY(),1))
```